# TypeScript scope of keyword 'this'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a problem with a scope of keyword 'this'.

The code for instance is:

```
class Burger {
    
    sleep() {
        // To sleep
    }
    
    pourSauce(sauce: string) {
        // To pour sauce
        this.sleep();
    }
}

class Hesburger extends Burger {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    
    private bun: string = 'bunny';
    
    foo(): void {
        this.tmp(this.fat);
    }

    private fat(): void {
        super.pourSauce(this.bun);
    }
    
    private tmp(callBack: () => void): void {
        callBack();
    }
}
```

Somewhere I call:

```
Hesburger.foo();
```

I receive the error:

> "bun" is undefined

I have found the [post](https://akumina.github.io/docs/Akumina-Widget-Scoping), describing the solution for transmitting a function. But no clue about a class's property.

Can someone advise to transit 'bun' variable's value 'bunny' to function *fat()*, so it would be transmitted further to function *pourSauce()*?

Thank you!

Comment: `foo` does not appear to be a static property, so you'd call `foo` on an instance of Hesburger, not the class. Is that what you mean? Are you trying to call `let instance = new Hesburger(); instance.foo();` rather than `Hesburger.foo()`?

Comment: Assuming that `Hesburger` is acually an instance of the `Hesburger` class (as otherwise that wouldn't even compile) I suppose the *exact* error message you are getting is `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bun') `, isn't it?

Comment: These are such weird names. Assuming you mean `new Hesburger().foo()`, you need to bind the `this` context for `this.fat` before you pass it as a callback, like `this.tmp(this.fat.bind(this));`, see [here](//tsplay.dev/WJ4yRN).  TypeScript fails to catch your problem due to a language limitation or missing feature; there is an (old) feature request at [ms/TS#7968](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7968) to strictly check `this` contexts.  Until and unless such a feature is implemented, you just have to be careful. Shall I write this up as an answer? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the following line

```
this.tmp(this.fat);
```

where you are passing the `fat` function as callback to the `tmp` function. But eventhough you are passing `this.fat` it is always just a function, that is not bound to a specific context (ie it does not have a defined `this` anymore). You can work around this issue by explicitely binding the function to a specific context

```
this.tmp(this.fat.bind(this))
```

Comment: alternatively, `foo(): void {  this.tmp(()=>this.fat());  }`

Comment: Wow! It amazingly worked out. I'm still not sure, what's going on in the context. But surely gonna make it clear for myself. Thank you very much!